# How do I align a div to the top when flex-direction is column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have two div tags in a container.  I want to use flex box and align the first div tag to the top and the other be centered relative to the container.  How can I do this?

Using `align-items: flex-start` only moves it to the left when flex-direction is column.  What is the equivalent css to move it to the top?

codepen: https://codepen.io/GMSg68/pen/aGpOpG

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}

.box div:nth-child(1) {
  /*  How do I push the first div tag to the top? */
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.box div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **the other be centered**. 

Both horizontally and vertically centered OR just horizontally centered?

Comment: The other to be centered both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add margin top and bottom auto to the nth-child(2) div. Then add a Y transform of -50% to align it to the centre. This assumes the two divs are the same height.

```
.box div:nth-child(2){
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work.